# How to get back result from a session

Tags: c#, .net, session, foreach, ienumerable

Work on entity frame work  vs2010

After execute my linq query get a list of records ,want to put this record in session .Now from session Want to get back my record list ,what to do how to get back record from a session

Linq query

```
 public IEnumerable GetSearchUserGroupPermissionData(int userID = 0)
        {
                var query = from p in this.Context.CmnPermissionGroupUsers
                        join q in this.Context.CmnPermissionGroups on p.PermissionGroupID equals q.PermissionGroupID
                        join r in this.Context.CmnPermissionGroupDocs on p.PermissionGroupID equals r.PermissionGroupID
                        join s in this.Context.CmnUserInfoes on p.UserID equals s.UserID
                        join t in this.Context.CmnDocLists on r.DocListID equals t.DocListID
                        //join u in this.Context.CmnModuleFormCompanies on t.ModuleID equals u.ModuleID
                        //join v in this.Context.CmnModuleLists on u.ModuleID equals v.ModuleID
                        //join w in this.Context.CmnFormLists on u.FormID equals w.FormID

                        where p.IsDeleted == false
                        select new
                        {
                            RecordID = p.PermissionGroupUserRecordID,
                            s.UserID,
                            s.UserFirstName,
                            q.PermissionGroupName,
                            p.EffectiveDate,
                            p.StatusID,
                            t.DocListID,
                            t.DocName,
                            t.ModuleID,
                           // v.ModuleName,
                           // u.FormID,
                            //          t.FormName,
                          //  w.FormName,
                            t.ParentID,
                            t.Sequence,
                            t.IsApprovalRequired,
                            t.CompanyCategoryID,                            
                            t.DocTypeID

                            //p.CreateBy,
                            //p.CreateOn,
                            //p.CreatePc,
                            //p.UpdateBy,
                            //p.UpdateOn,
                            //p.UpdatePc,
                            //p.IsDeleted,
                            //p.DeleteBy,
                            //p.DeleteOn,
                            //p.DeletePc,
                            //p.Transfer
                        };   
         return query.WhereIf(userID != 0, w => w.UserID == userID).ToList();    
        }
```

Put result in session

```
Session["UserPermission"] = new PermissionGroupUserController().GetSearchUserGroupPermissionData(objEntity.UserID);
```

Now ,want to get back the record set from session.bellow foreach syntax area as a item contain each row all properties and values but can not assign in a variable just like bellow ,why can not assign an AnonymousType variable value to a variable.
[image]
 var o = Session["UserPermission"] as IEnumerable;  //use casting
            foreach (var area in o)
            {
                //int a = area.UserID;
            }

Note:sabove syntax how me error

> message:foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object'
>   because 'object' does not contain a public definition for
>   'GetEnumerator'

If have any query please ask.

Comment: If you know the type of variable `o`. Explicit cast the `Session["UserPermission"]` using that type.

Comment: Your session issue aside, you should consider using a Membership and/or RoleProvider here.  Session management can be a separate headache on top of trying to maintain a secure application.

Comment: `var o = Session` - and error `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object'` - you need to cast it to the proper type. The way you have it is assigning a object to var and trying to iterate over it. *I agree with @GlennFerrieLive you should not use Sessions for membership info.*

Comment: Freddie Fabregas ,thanks for reply,please check my edit,use casting but now can not use the AnonymousType variable.Help me to use AnonymousType properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try typecasting `o`to `IEnumerable`?

Apart from that, in your `foreach` loop, you have to use `dynamic` instead of `var`. This is required because your type is anonymous.

But i would still strongly suggest you to use normal types instead of Anonumous ones atleast for two reasons

1. Code reusability.
2. Better code readability.

Comment: James Poulose,thanks for reply,yes i did it,After cast can retrive value from session but now face a problem can not use AnonymousType .please check my edit.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Kirk you are right, i should have posted my suggestion in the comment section. But now i have an answer for OP :-) - Thanks anyways.

Comment: James Poulose thanks ,dynamic dt= Session["UserPermission"];  foreach (dynamic item in dt) { int a = item.UserID; }
After use dynamic get error message: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'UserID'

Comment: @shamim That's because your anonymous type does not have a property 'UserID'. To fix that change your anonymous type creation from 's.UserID' to 'UserID = s.UserID'.